# How to list all imported games in gym retro?

Tags: openai-gym

I've imported some ROMs into gym retro via `python3 -m retro.import path/to/roms`, everything works fine. But now I want to see a list of the available games. For gym there's the following way to get all available enviromements:

```
from gym import envs
all_envs = envs.registry.all()
```

But this doesn't include the retro games I imported. Sure there's a complete list of [all integrated games](https://github.com/openai/retro/tree/master/retro/data/stable) but I want to look up which ones I have available on my machine. The [official documentation](https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) doesn't help much. Any ideas how to do this?